# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath called many times

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an app with an `UICollectionView` gallery. I have subclassed a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I've enabled `pageEnabled property`.

My gallery works very good with images but I also have comments of every image that I download from the service every time I change the picture using the picture code. When I change from one image to next or the picture before, I change a `property` value and in its `custom setter` I call a method to download those comments.

The problem is when I go ahead to next picture the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is called 3 times, firs time with the next image information(What I need), second time with the image where I am and third time with the next image information again(What I need). If this image does not have too many comments this happens very quickly so nobody gets notice. But, when I am changing to the next image but I change my mind in the middle of the next image and get back to the image where I am. I get wrong image comments for the image where I am.

Everything happens if I go back in the gallery.

How can I manage this? Is possible to know if the cell is completely displayed? If I could know when the cell is completely displayed I could call the webService method and download that information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Just go to Storyboard. Choose your CollectionView then go to -> Attribute Inspector-> **Uncheck** the **prefetching Enable property**. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer -  [collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView%3adidEndDisplayingCell%3aforItemAtIndexPath%3a)

You will know when your cell in Collection is loaded .
So you can get proper comments for loaded cell in collection view.

Hope it helps ?

Comment: Sorry, it's still doing the same. I am using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and it seems that it is working good. Anyway, Thank you

Comment: My way is not working too. Could you explain yours? Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to use caching of comments instead of making call while scrolling you prefetch comments and show whenever need it will improve user experience and also it will solve your problem to.

Comment: This app is a kind of 500px, I do not think they cache comments.

Comment: Instead of fetching all comments at time fetch minimum (say 10) all remaining comments can be fetch when user actual select comments for image. Try to add this comments fetching work to background thread. you can use concept called Lazy fetching you can refer this http://swati-ios.blogspot.in/2012/05/lazy-loading-of-images-in-table-ios-50.html link for it hope it helps..:)

Comment: I know Lazy loading and I already do it, but.. what I don't understand is how to download comments of each image before I am watching that image.

Comment: you have done it then apply same for fetching comments also you can follow these steps - when startloading image send async request for comments also till then you can show activity indicatior on comments part of UI, after fetching comments you can stop activity indicatot and allow user to see comments , is it make sense ?

Comment: This is what I already do, but I was talking about what you say of caching comments before.